# Any way to convert STL to .max?

Tags: file-format, conversion

I can draw what I need on SketchUp (Maker free version of 2017). It can export on STL, which is fine  for 3D printer, but now I need to feed my object into a `website that only accepts .max` files.

I have not found any way to convert STL to .max. The closest I got is with `openctm-tools` on linux which can make a .3ds. Blender seems to not have export functionality to .max, so I thought you guys may have a solution on how to convert to .max stargin from a STL or other common format. Any suggestions?

Comment: `.max` is a binary file format which you only can create using [3ds Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max).

Comment: That is super bad news, I am on mac so 3DS Max is not even an option. I tried on Vin10 virtual machine but it failed to install, which is a super bummer as I can get the software from school.

Comment: In any case thanks for the input. Now I know I have to get a 3DS working installation ...